# Deploy C++ MFC application with folder strucuture and .ini file

Tags: c++, deployment, mfc, installshield, ini

Good Morning,

I have a C++ MFC application generated with VS2013 that I would like to deploy. I am storing some persistent values in an .ini file in a certain location on the c-drive.

How can I create an install version that automatically creates this folder structure for me and puts the .ini file there?

I already experimented with the free version of Installshield but I cannot make the folder/.ini generation work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ini files are usually in the same folder where is the executable, you should be able to create install package which will copy the ini files in the app folder, however it may be much better approach (especially if ini is on c) to create it initially with the executable,  check if the ini file exists and if not create it filled with default values

Comment: Ok, so the Install package will generate the folder structure but the ini file is written whenever the user clicks ApplicationName.exe? One issue may be that I am also specifying communication parameters within the ini file and the user may need to change those before he starts the application.

Comment: Ok, but what will happen if someone delete or corrupt the ini file? Your app should not crash but display an error message and create a new ini file filled with the default values. Otherwise you should print message that the application is corrupted and must be reinstalled. Usually you have some default values in the exe and default values from the INI overwrites them. Try with InstallCreator or some easy to work app if you can copy the ini at the path you want. Also you may have to delete the ini files on uninstall.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am already creating a default ini file if I cannot find one and tell the user to check the values. I am going to check out InstallCreator. Thanks!